# URL, NSURL - compiler errors in code from the standard samples

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift2, nsurl

m.b. I'm asking stupid question, but I'm really newbie in Swift and iPhone programming. Using `XCode 8.0`.
I want to create `WebView` application and have taken next code from here: https://sourcefreeze.com/uiwebview-example-using-swift-in-ios/

**My Code :**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Of course I've created UI object of `UIWebView` and connected it to controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!
```

During the build I receive next red alert:

**'NSURL' is not implicitly convertible to 'URL'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?**

As I understand this code worked perfectly before 2 years. I guess that I'm missing something, but what?
Thanks for advance.

Comment: *"this code worked perfectly before 2 years"* – Swift changed *a lot* in the last two years. In particular Swift 3 that comes with Xcode 8. You might have a look at the release notes and the migration guide https://swift.org/migration-guide/.

Comment: NSURL type is changed to URL in swift 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `URL` instead of `NSURL` as it is replaced with `URL` type in Swift 3

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com")
```

Here is the instruction from apple developer forum

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the URL
>   structure, which bridges to the NSURL class. The URL value type offers
>   the same functionality as the NSURL reference type, and the two can be
>   used interchangeably in Swift code that interacts with Objective-C
>   APIs. This behavior is similar to how Swift bridges standard string,
>   numeric, and collection types to their corresponding Foundation
>   classes.
>
> For more information about value types, see Classes and Structures in
>   The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3) and Working with Cocoa
>   Frameworks in Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 3).

Answer (score 0):

It is the simplest way to solve issue:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com")!
myWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
```

Xcode often tales you what is wrong. So from Xcode message it is possible to understand that NSURL should be converted to URL. Try to read relevant resources and bot use old tutorials. Swift is dynamically changes language always try to use up to date resources.

Comment: The second string gives me error: Missing argument for parameter ‘mimeType’ in call

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com")))
myWebView.delegate = self;
self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
```

Comment: I receive error: Cannot convert value of type ’NSURL’ to expected argument type ‘URL’

Comment: use Swift native type String and use guard to make sure data it is not nil

Answer (score 0):

This code worked:

```
    let myUrl = URL (string: "http://www.sourcefreeze.com")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: myUrl);
    myWebView.loadRequest(request);
```

Now the WebView is invisible, but I'll try firstly to search the solution in a forum.